# Bootstrap grid layout alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Link to my project](https://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/pen/zwaEEw?editors=1100), I've been working on this project to make my portfolio, the grids of my expertise, portfolio and education block aren't aligning with respect to screen size, it remains to the left on large screen, please provide me necessary changes to be made so overcome this problem.
Ps: if I use "center" for alignment in these block, the website still doesn't work properly.

```
 <div class="content container-fluid">
      <h1 align="center">My Expertise</h1>
        <div class="projects conatiner-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <i class="fa fa-code fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" align="center"></i>
              <div class="id1">
                <h3 align="center">CODE</h3>
                <p>I'm a versatile programmer with knowledge and interest to learn and code in any language</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" align="center"></i>
              <div class="id2">
                <h3 align="center">UI/UX</h3>
                <p>I'm a front-end developer and UI/UX designer who loves building and designing websites from scratch</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" align="center"></i>
              <div class="id3">
                <h3>Machine Learning</h3>
                <p>I'm keenly interested in machine learning and I have implemented a project to detect Hand-written digits using python</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="projects">
        <div>
          <h1 align="center">Portfolio</h1></div>
        <div class="conatiner-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/full/LymmKO/"><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/mw5vki.png" class="img-responsive" align="center" alt="Nikola Tesla"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/full/LymmKO/"><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/mw5vki.png" class="img-responsive" align="center" alt="Nikola Tesla"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/full/LymmKO/"><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/mw5vki.png" class="img-responsive" align="center" alt="Nikola Tesla"> </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="conatiner-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/full/LymmKO/"><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/mw5vki.png" class="img-responsive" align="center" alt="Nikola Tesla"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/full/LymmKO/"><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/mw5vki.png" class="img-responsive" align="center" alt="Nikola Tesla"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/full/LymmKO/"><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/mw5vki.png" class="img-responsive" align="center" alt="Nikola Tesla"> </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="education">
        <div>
          <h1 align="center">My Education</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="projects container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x" aria-hidden="true" align="center"></i>
              <div class="id1">
                <h3 align="center">Secondary Education</h3>
                <p>Passed out secondary education with a percentage of 89.6% from ICSE board</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" align="center"></i>
              <div class="id2">
                <h3 align="center">High Secondary Education</h3>
                <p>Passed out higher secondary education from CBSE board with science as stream scoring 85%</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
              <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" align="center"></i>
              <div class="id3">
                <h3>Undergraduate</h3>
                <p>Graduate from Jalpaiguri Goevrnment Engineering College with Bachelor in Information Technology with a CGPA of 8</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hireme" align="center">
        <p>Want to get in touch with me, please fill the contact information and I'll respond as soon as possible
          <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn1">
          <span>I'm Available for Hire</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="mylinks" align="center">
        <footer>Designed and Coded by <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/nilabja10201992"><em>Nilabja Bhattacharya</em></a></footer>
        <div class="icons" align="center">
          <a href="https://github.com/nilabja10201992"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/nilabja10201992"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.quora.com/profile/Nilabja-Bhattacharya"><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://codepen.io/nilabja10201992/"><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/nilabja10201992/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6157670/nilabja-bhattacharya?tab=profile"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.row` has a max-width of 75rem. Overwrite this by:

```
.row {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much, problem got solved solved! :D I hope I could upvote.